# How to ensure an async function runs before another in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I run a server-side script on NodeJS to update a database. I first collect and summarize existing fields and then update new fields.

```js
const User = require('./models/user');

// Summarize
User.summarizeAllUsers();

// Update
User.updateAllUsers();
```

The functions are asynchronous because I want to wait for the return of getting all users:

```js
UserSchema.statics.summarize = async function() {

  let users = await this.getAllUsers();
  // ...
}
```

So obviously, `summarize()` may run after `update()` and I confirm in the logs with `console.log()` that it is so. My solution has been to split the functions in two different scripts, and I sometimes forget to run both.

How can I keep them in a single script and ensure that one completes before the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your await statements before calling those functions and wrap them in another async function:

```
const User = require('./models/user');
async function doSomething() {
// Summarize
await User.summarizeAllUsers();

// Update
await User.updateAllUsers();
}

doSomething();
```

alternatively use promises and put the `updateAllUsers` call within the `then` of the `summarizeAllUsers` call. Don't forget `Try/Catch` with the above to catch any errors

Comment: I confirm that this works in the right order, and it has the advantage of nesting multiple sequential commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
const User = require('./models/user');

User.summarizeAllUsers().then(()=>{ User.updateAllUsers() }).catch((e) => return e);
```